# Fetch SelectedItem in viewmodel from Listview in WPF

Tags: wpf, viewmodel, selecteditem

I have a List View. I want to get the Id of the selected Employee.
I thought Selected Employee will give the all details of selected row 
and then I can get the Id by SelectedEmployee.EmpId. it doesnt work

This is my XAML:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1" Name="listViewTask" ItemsSource="{Binding Employees}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEmployee, Mode=TwoWay}"  Margin="1,25,0,10" Foreground="Black" SelectionChanged="ListView_SelectionChanged" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" >
        <ListView.View  >
            <GridView  >
        <GridViewColumn Header="EmpId" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding EmpId}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Created Date" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding created_date}"/>

    </GridView>
        </ListView.View>

    </ListView>
```

This is my property in ViewModel:

```
private string selectedEmployee;
public string SelectedEmployee
{
    get { return this.selectedEmployee; }  
    set
    {
        // Implement with property changed handling for INotifyPropertyChanged

        if (!string.Equals((this.selectedEmployee), value))  
        {
            this.selectedEmployee = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged(selectedEmployee); // Method to raise the PropertyChanged event in your BaseViewModel class...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are these Employee only strings, or are they complete classes? Because in the second case the SelectedEmployee class must be an Employee too.

Answer (score 0):

As per the code provided by you, the `SelectedEmployee` is of type string. The way you are trying to achieve is not possible with such a code. 
Either you’re mistaken or you need to learn more about WPF/MVVM. I hope `Employees` is also of type `IEnumerable<String>`.

If you want to get the selected employee ID from a selected item, first create a data class like this for employees

```
public class EmployeeData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private Guid empID;

        public Guid EmpId
        {
            get { return empID; }
            set
            {
                empID = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(empID);
            }
        }

        private string empName;

        public string EmpName
        {
            get { return empName; }
            set
            {
                empName = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(empName);
            }
        }
}
```

Then in your viewmodel create a list like this and make it your listbox’s itemsource:

```
private ObservableCollection<EmployeeData> employees;
public ObservableCollection<EmployeeData> Employees
{    
    get
    {
        return employees;
    }    
    set
    {
        employees = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(“employees”);
    }    
}
```

And also a property to hold the selected item like this :

```
private EmployeeData selectedEmployee;
public EmployeeData SelectedEmployee
{
    get { return this.selectedEmployee; }  
    set
    {
        // Implement with property changed handling for INotifyPropertyChanged

        if (!string.Equals((this.selectedEmployee), value))  
        {
            this.selectedEmployee = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged(selectedEmployee); // Method to raise the PropertyChanged event in your BaseViewModel class...
        }
    }
}
```

**Ensure that the `selectedEmployee` is of type `EmployeeData` and not string. 
Now you can access the ID like `SelectedEmployee.EmpID`**